# Displaying a custom taxonomy term's name & description

Tags: custom-taxonomy, description

How can I display a term's name & description for a custom taxonomy within The Loop (single post page template)?

Currently I can show its name like this:

```
the_terms( $post->ID , 'director', 'director: ');
```

but can't get the description

**EDIT**
I dont want to use extra php coding like:

```
$directors = get_the_terms($post->ID ,'director');
foreach($directors as $director){
    $director_name = $director->name;
    $director_desc = $director->description;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you: [get_the_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms)

Comment: I should do some itteration uppon using `get_the_term`. I will add edit to clear out my question more. thanks though

Comment: You could put a custom function in your `functions.php` and call it from your template files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`get term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term). This return the name and description for a term.

Here is the axamples given in the codex

> Gives you term name: e.g. Term Name Example
>
> $name = $term->name;
>
> Gives you term description: e.g. This is my new cool custom term.
>
> $desc = $term->description;

Comment: documentation: `Get all Term data from database by Term ID`. I dont want to contact DB again!

Answer (score 0):

Get the term first

```
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'category-slug', 'taxonomy' );
```

Display the description

```
echo $current_term->description;
```